# compiling a smoke test

Tags: solidity, ganache

I was testing my ganache compiler to see if it is working and I came across the most ridiculous set of errors

This is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Token {
  string public name = "My Name";
}
```

This is the console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1072:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at Object.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Function.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/config/dist/index.js:161:1)
    at Function.detect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/config/dist/index.js:150:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/compile.js:68:1)
    at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:136:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/cli.js:57:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:83:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:89:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
Truffle v5.1.63 (core: 5.1.63)
Node v15.5.0
```

I feel like it has to do with other files I have open and not the code itself. What do you think?

Comment: The Solidity code compiles correctly, so the error might be related to something else. What command and parameters did you use to compile?

Comment: I used ```truffle compile```

Comment: This is how I configured truffle,

Comment: ```require('babel-register');
require('babel-polyfill');
require('dotenv') config();



module.exports = {
  

  networks: {
   development : {
    host : "127.0.0.1",
    port: 7545,
    netowrk_id: "*"
   },
 
  },
contracts_directory:'./src/contracts/'.
contracts_build_directory: './src/abis/',
 
  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
     optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 200
     }
    }
  }
}; ``` As you you can see I used Javascript to connect my project to my Ethereum node, is there a problem there?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it looks that there are some formatting issues in your truffle config. I have done three changes that might help:

```
require('babel-register');
require('babel-polyfill');
require('dotenv').config(); // you are missing the dot `.` between `require('dotenv')` and `config()`

module.exports = {
    networks: {
        development:
        {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 7545,
            netowrk_id: "*"
        },
    },
    contracts_directory: './src/contracts/', // there was a dot `.` at the end of this line, where it should be a comma
    contracts_build_directory: './src/abis/',
    // Configure your compilers   
    compilers: {
        solc: {
            version: "0.5.0", // you are missing your Solidity compiler version
            optimizer: {
                enabled: true,
                runs: 200
            }
        }
    }
};
```